# Java regular expression subsearch in a single process?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get an HTML source code meta tag "name" attribute value in a single regular expression. Is this possible?
Right now I'm running a regular expression to get all meta tags:

```
"<meta.*?>"
```

I'm storing all matches into a List<String>, and then I run a second regular expression on those results to get the "name" attribute value:

```
"name=\".*?\""
```

Is there a way of doing this with a single regular expression? I just want to store the "name" attribute ONLY of meta tags, ignoring other HTML tags.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an HTML parser for this?

Comment: Yep, Jsoup can cleanly and easily do this in a few lines of code.

Comment: That's nice but any parser that knows xpath can easily do it in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=<meta).*?name\\s*=\\s*\"(.*)\"");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Your list (matchList ) in the end should contain the desired result which will be the values of all name attributes.

Finally as you will see in all posts related with xml/html and regexes the norm is to go for a parser instead of a regex. However if you task is so simple you can do it with a regex easily.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup (and other HTML parsers) can do this cleanly and easily:

```
   public static List<String> parseForMeta(String htmlText) {
      Document jsDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlText);
      Elements metaElements = jsDocument.select("meta[name]");
      List<String> metaList = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (Element element : metaElements) {
         metaList.add(element.toString());
      }

      return metaList;
   }
```

**EDIT:**  But heck, you already know this from your last thread!?